# take complete structure from XML but only filtered childs with xslt/xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i need some help in filtering an xml document with xpath in an xslt stylesheet.
The xml document look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constants>
    <entry key="KundenAuftragsnummer">
        <msg lang="EN">Customer Order Number</msg>
        <msg lang="DE">Kunden-Auftragsnummer</msg>
    </entry>
   <entry key="UnserZeichen">
      <msg lang="EN">our reference</msg>
      <msg lang="DE">Unser Zeichen</msg>
   </entry>
   ........
```

here's my xslt
   .........

```
   <xsl:variable
      name="lang"
      select="Invoice/@language"></xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable
      name="langText"
      select="document('Ausgangsrechnung Texte.xml')//*[msg[@lang=$lang]]">
    </xsl:variable>
```

I want a document in $langText that keeps the whole structure but only msg elements
with a matching language.
Can this be achieved with a single xpath expression?
Pls. help.

Siggi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be achieved with a single xpath expression?

No, because an XPath expression *selects* nodes out if an existing tree, whereas you want to *construct* new entry elements that have a subset of the children that the original entry elements had.

If you want to send this filtered tree to the output then use appropriate templates to strip out the msg elements with the wrong language. If you're just building a lookup table for later use then use what you currently have, which will set `langText` to the set of entry elements that have a msg in the appropriate language, but then filter at lookup time

```
<xsl:value-of select="$langText[@key='...']/msg[@lang=$lang]"/>
```

Or alternatively, set the variable to hold the `msg` elements rather than the entries and look them up with a predicate on their parents

```
<xsl:variable
  name="lang"
  select="Invoice/@language"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable
  name="langText"
  select="document('Ausgangsrechnung Texte.xml')/constants/entry/msg[@lang=$lang]">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$langText[../@key='...']"/>
```